# Mathieu Characteristics Cross When Plotted

Tags: python, scipy, physics

I need to plot the mathieu characteristic parameters for various q. The plot should show 'flute' shapes going from wide on the left, to very narrow on the right. The code below does this, but it also introduces a handful of inter-band jumps (obvious from the plotted figure). How can I fix this?

Thank you!

AM

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.special as spfun
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

uplim =120#E_rec
Npts =1000 
Nstates =8 
q = np.linspace(0, uplim/4.0, Npts)
EA = np.zeros([Npts,Nstates])
EB = np.zeros([Npts,Nstates])
U = 4*q 

print np.shape(EA)    #plt.fill_between(U, EA[:,i], EB[:,i]) #plt.plot(U,Ea,U,Eb) 
for i in range(Nstates):
    a = spfun.mathieu_a(i,q)
    b = spfun.mathieu_b(i+1,q)
    EA[:,i] = a + 2*q
    EB[:,i] = b + 2*q 
    plt.fill_between(U, EA[:,i], EB[:,i]) #plt.plot(U,Ea,U,Eb) 

print np.shape(EA)    #plt.fill_between(U, EA[:,i], EB[:,i]) #plt.plot(U,Ea,U,Eb) 
plt.show()
```

[image: image of problem]

*EDIT* As DSM and pv have pointed out, this is a scipy bug. The glitches get worse as you go out further. What I ended up doing was exporting tables of values that I wanted from Mathematica, and importing them into python and interpolating. Not great, but works.

Comment: FWIW, this looks to me like an evaluation error in `mathieu_a`.  Depending on your needs, you might be able to get away with simply patching the function during the difficult regions.

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug, reported at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4479

Answer (score 1):

I tried computing this with the latest release of the [NAG Library for Python](https://www.nag.co.uk/nag-library-python) which included a new Mathieu function routine.
I pushed a little harder -- more states and a higher value of uplim.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.special as spfun
from naginterfaces.library import specfun
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

uplim =150#E_rec
Npts = 4000 
Nstates = 10
q = np.linspace(0, uplim/4.0, Npts)
EA = np.zeros([Npts,Nstates])
EB = np.zeros([Npts,Nstates])
U = 4*q 

plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.title('Using SciPy')

for i in range(Nstates):
    a = spfun.mathieu_a(i,q)
    b = spfun.mathieu_b(i+1,q)
    EA[:,i] = a + 2*q
    EB[:,i] = b + 2*q 
    plt.fill_between(U, EA[:,i], EB[:,i]) #plt.plot(U,Ea,U,Eb) 


plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.title('Using NAG')

for i in range(Nstates):
    a = [specfun.mathieu_ang_periodic_real(ordval=i, q=qi, parity=0, mode=3)[2] for qi in q]
    b = [specfun.mathieu_ang_periodic_real(ordval=i+1, q=qi, parity=1, mode=3)[2] for qi in q]
    EA[:,i] = a + 2*q
    EB[:,i] = b + 2*q 
    plt.fill_between(U, EA[:,i], EB[:,i]) 

plt.show()
```

[image: Mathieu function characteristic]

This uses Mark 27 of the NAG Library and version 1.2.1 of ScipPy